# How find the possible eigenvalue of $P$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question 1:**

Let $P$ be a real matrix such that $$P^{T}=P^2$$ What are the possible eigenvalues of $P$? I consider sometimes, But I can't, and I guess $1$ and $-1$? Thank you

**Question 2：** if $P$ is complex matrix, such that $P^T=P^2$, then what are the possible eigenvalues of $P$?

Question 1 has been solved by Sami Ben Romdhane, but question 2 is still not solved.

Thank you very much!Thank you

Comment: Now,I Now I'm not sure whether the $-1$ is  P eigenvalues

Comment: yes,so I guess it have no $-1$ eigenvalues,becasuse I can't have example,Thank you

Comment: If you are not satisfied with Sami's answer, then you should possibly explain in your question, what is different from that to which Sami answered. For instance, you should make explcite whether you consider the transpose or the conjugate transpose (and then possibly adapt the symbols in the formula if needed). For a simple "transposed" the eigenvalues of $P$ and of $P^T$ are the same as far as I remember ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since $P^T=P^2$ so $$P=(P^T)^T=(P^T)^2=(P^2)^2=P^4$$ hence the polynomial $x^4-x=x(x^3-1)$ annihilates the matrix $P$ and then its roots $0,1,e^{2i\pi/3}$ and $e^{4i\pi/3}$ are the expected eigenvalues of $P$.

Comment: Thank you,if $P$ is complex ?

Comment: @math110 It's exactly the same.

Comment: why? I know if $P$ is complex matrix,then we can't have $P=(P^T)^T=(P^T)^2$

Comment: @math110 Why wouldn't that be true? If $P^T=P^2$, then $P=(P^T)^T=(P^2)^T=(P^T)^2=(P^2)^2=P^4$. Why should complex numbers make the computation invalid?

Comment: because when $p=\begin{bmatrix} 2+i&3+i\\4+i&5+i\end{bmatrix}$,then $P^T=\begin{bmatrix}2-i&4-i\\3-i&5-i\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I believe you are thinking of the conjugate transpose which is normally written $P^{*}$ instead of $P^{T}$.

Comment: @math110 The reasoning is ***exactly*** the same if you consider the conjugate transpose.

Comment: Math110, P=I is a trival example of a complex matrix satisfying the identity you suspect cannot happen. Any real matrix satisfying the identity is a complex one. Requiring the original identity for conjugate transpose definitely changes the problem.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. Why? What the "answer" shows is the following: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $P$, then $\lambda\in\{0,1,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i/3},\mathrm{e}^{4\pi i/3}\}=\varLambda$. It does not show however that for every $\lambda\in\varLambda$, there is a matrix $P$, satisfying $P^T=P^2$ and having $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: Very impressive, and some bounty, too!

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the answer (in the case $P$ real matrix) one needs to provide examples of matrices which satisfy the relation $P^T=P^2$, and having each of the eigenvalues $\{0,1,\mathrm{e}^{2\pi i/3},\mathrm{e}^{4\pi i/3}\}$.

Such examples are $P=0$, with only one eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, $P=I$, with only one eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ and 
$$
P=\left(\begin{matrix} \cos(2\pi/3) & \sin(2\pi/3) \\ -\sin(2\pi/3) & \cos(2\pi/3)
\end{matrix}\right).
$$